# Shopify Theme Kit file error: "contains illegal characters"

Tags: file, shopify, naming-conventions, liquid, naming

I'm having this weirdest issue with adding hero banners to my Shopify store today. I've been making this particular set of changes multiple times over the past 6 weeks or so without any issues whatsoever. What I've been scouring the internet for is a list of "illegal" characters so I can be sure I'm not going to have this same issue going forward. Anyone know where to find that?

Ex. this is what it normally looks like in my Theme Kit upload:

```
20:41:10 [development] processing assets/2021-05-24_Generic_Desktop-Slider-(1450x500).jpg
20:41:12 [development] Updated assets/2021-05-24_Generic_Desktop-Slider-(1450x500).jpg
```

What I got instead was this:

```
20:41:07 [development] processing assets/2021-05-19_Subscribe+Save_Desktop-Slider-V1-(1450x500).jpg
[development] (assets/2021-05-19_Subscribe+Save_Desktop-Slider-V1-(1450x500).jpg) "assets/2021-05-19_Subscribe+Save_Desktop-Slider-V1-(1450x500).jpg" contains illegal characters
```

Anyone else have this problem? Thoughts, comments, suggestions? Know a place where I can find a list of `illegal` characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is the only time that I've had a file name with a `+` in it, and as I'm writing this, I'm changing it to a `-` which seems to have done the trick... *this* time!

Comment: It was a `.` to a `-` for me